# CSS: make element scroll with page within container div

Tags: html, css

This must have been asked before, but I could not find the right answer.

So I want to create a social bar, like treehouse blog has: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/android-libraries-use-every-project

I'm thinking: is it possible to do it with pure css without javascript or jquery?
Point is: it should only appear next to my content div, neither before it starts, nor after it ends. And of course it should scroll with the div.

Any idea?

Comment: A bottle of Heineken for whoever can do this without Javascript, I'll be at the bar.

Comment: I assume you're talking about the free floating social too bar on the left.

Comment: Using CSS is irrational, this is what jQuery/javascript was created for

Comment: Yes, this requires JS.

Comment: There is [`position:sticky` in the CSS Positioned Layout Module Level 3 working draft](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-position-3/#sticky-positioning), that would get you at least halfway there I guess … but it is currently not ready for use, and only experimentally implemented in some browsers.